# NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService

Tags: angular

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injector, APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LOCATION_INITIALIZED } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AngularSlickgridModule, GridOdataService, ResizerService} from 'angular-slickgrid';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstgridComponent } from './firstgrid/firstgrid.component';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
export function appInitializerFactory(translate: TranslateService, injector: Injector) {
  return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
    const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
    locationInitialized.then(() => {
      const langToSet = 'en';
      translate.setDefaultLang('en');
      translate.use(langToSet).subscribe(() => {
        // console.info(`Successfully initialized '${langToSet}' language.'`);
      }, err => {
        console.error(`Problem with '${langToSet}' language initialization.'`);
      }, () => {
        resolve(null);
      });
    });
  });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstgridComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
      deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
      multi: true
    },
    GridOdataService,
    ResizerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm creating a slikgrid component in angular. I'm import all the libraries, but got the following errors.

```
GridBasicComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularSlickgridComponent -> TranslateService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularSlickgridComponent -> TranslateService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8369)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9057)
    at resolveDep (core.js:9422)
```

after write that code I got an error that "slick.cellrangedecorator.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".
And in terminal error is like -- 
ERROR in node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filter-conditions/index.d.ts(2,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: Did you inject the `TranslateService`? How did you inject it. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Yeah. I did.  import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';    providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
      deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
      multi: true
    }
  ]

Comment: @santanuDhabal have you add `TranslateModule.forRoot()` in appMudule?

Comment: I'm also add this.  TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })

Comment: It is difficult to attack the problem when we have so little information. It would be helpful if you could post some of the code in app.module. And also, when do you get the error? Is it during `ng serve`? Is it a compile error from your IDE? Is it a run-time error?

Comment: It is compile time error

Comment: That seems to be that you forgot to add the necessary scripts in your `angular.json` which are required (read the [HOWTO](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step), that or `ngx-translate` is not configured correctly. Also make sure to use the correct version of `ngx-translate` depending on your Angular version